# React Native set flow of functions calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i wrote this piece of code

```
componentDidMount(){
    
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(info => {
        console.log(info.coords.latitude + "    " + info.coords.longitude)
        this.setState({coords: {latitude: info.coords.latitude, longitude: info.coords.longitude, latitudeDelta: this.LATITUDE_DELTA, longitudeDelta: this.LONGITUDE_DELTA}})
    }, error => Alert.alert('Error', JSON.stringify(error)),
    {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000});
      
    console.log(this.state.coords.latitude + "    " + this.state.coords.longitude);

    region = getapi(this.state.coords.latitude, this.state.coords.longitude)
    this.setState({region})
    console.log("TEMP: " + region);
    hot = getHotBarb(this.state.region)
    this.setState({hot})
    rated = getRatedBarb(this.state.region)
    this.setState({rated})
    offer = getOfferBarb(this.state.region)
    this.setState({offer})

    this.setState({loading: false})

}
```

But on the log console I see first the log of this.state.coords.latitude + " " + this.state.coords.longitude (that is undefined) and the log inside the getCurrentPosition call (that is correct).
The problem is that I can't call the function getapi because this.state.coords.latitude, this.state.coords.longitude results undefined
I need to set first `this.state.coords.latitude` and `this.state.coords.longitude` and then call the other functions in `componentDidMount()`.

How can i get setState on the getCurrentPosition function to be called before the other functions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this way

```
callApi(){

    console.log(this.state.coords.latitude + "    " + this.state.coords.longitude);

    region = getapi(this.state.coords.latitude, this.state.coords.longitude)
    this.setState({region})
    console.log("TEMP: " + region);
    hot = getHotBarb(this.state.region)
    this.setState({hot})
    rated = getRatedBarb(this.state.region)
    this.setState({rated})
    offer = getOfferBarb(this.state.region)
    this.setState({offer})

    this.setState({loading: false})
}


getCurrentPosition(){

    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(info => {
        console.log(info.coords.latitude + "    " + info.coords.longitude);

        this.setState({coords: {latitude: info.coords.latitude, longitude: info.coords.longitude, latitudeDelta: this.LATITUDE_DELTA, longitudeDelta: this.LONGITUDE_DELTA}},
    () => this.callApi();  // call api here
    )

    }, error => Alert.alert('Error', JSON.stringify(error)),
    {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000});
}


componentDidMount(){    
    this.getCurrentPosition();
}
```